# httaccess redirect rule

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I have a domain abc.com and domain has no SSL. Also there is folder "test" under the public_html. (abc.com/test). So I want to redirect all requests to https://abc.com/test to http://abc.com/test .

So Please let me know the rule which i need to add on htaccess file.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this i guess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Rather check `%{HTTPS} ^on$`